# Problem with chemfig :

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I need to draw the following scheme of equilibrium state of Fluorescein
[image]

Using `chemfig` package, and here's my code for that:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
    O=[:-54]*5(-O-(-*6(-(*6(-=-(-OH)=-=))--O-(*6(=-(-OH)=-=-))--))-(*6(-=-=-=))--)
}
\end{document}
```

The only problem I have is I can't get rid of the bond shown in the result of the previous code, any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want this way?

I started writing the molecule by the central hexagon.

I find it easiest to start at the center and place the other parts of the molecule around the central hexagon.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-O-(*6(=-(-OH)=-=))--([:84]*5(-(*6(-=-=-))--(=O)-O-))-(*6(-=-(-HO)=-))-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{
        O=[:-54]*5(-O-?(-[:210]*6(-=-(-HO)=-(-O-[:30]*6(=-(-OH)=-=?-))=))-(*6(-=-=-=))--)
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]